# Forgot Pattern and now cannot Erase Remotely

Tags: locked-out, google-pixel-2

So I ended up forgetting my pattern lock. (I'm sure I remembered it yet no luck.  Maybe too many attempts and no info from google)

I went to Android Device Manager and tried the lock function to set a password, but received the dreaded "this device is already locked" so the password I set isn't used.

Then I rebooted the phone.

Then after some more pattern attempts I decided to just erase it and hope the google backup sync has my data, otherwise my adb backup from 1 month ago should be good.

**So I went back to Android Device Manger to try erasing it, and now it cannot connect to the phone!!**

The sim is just fine.  It is connected to my home wifi and has full bars on cellular.

What are my options?

How can I contact google?  There is no contact phone or chat support!

(Running Android 8 or 9 on Pixel 2)

Answer (score 1):

Needed to boot into recovery mode.

You can follow the video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFaq4g-oa2Q, but these are the steps:

1. Press and hold the power button for a few seconds
2. Tap the Power Off option when the Power Menu appears
3. Wait for the Pixel 2 or Pixel 2 XL to completely turn off
4. Then press and hold the Power button and the Volume Down button at the same time
5. Continue holding these two buttons down until you boot into Fastboot Mode
6. Press the Volume Down button twice until Recovery is highlighted
7. Then press the Power button to select this option
8. Wait for the Pixel 2 to reboot and the splash screen to appear
9. Hold the Power button, and press the Volume Up button once and release.  You should you see the transition to Recovery Mode screen - let go of the power button.

Wipe the phone and reboot.

Now you can restore from cloud backups through the setup screens.

---

Here is the worst part:

A while back Google disabled the feature of using your google account instead of the pattern lock when locked out.  Everyone complained.  Now after wiping, it says you must use the old pattern, but it also has the option to bypass using your google account!!! Incredible!

Update:

Unrooted backups restore almost nothing! Surprise! 
(Good thing I had a solid 2FA restore plan.)
To gain real backups (untested!) you must root, which would open up security holes.

Sorry google, I'm going back to apple and never coming back.